# Vmware/Virtualbox Use host's IP address

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I have created a Windows Server 2008 guest from a Linux host but I am having trouble making the guest use the same IP address as the host. Currently the guest is being assigned an IP such as 192.168.21.1 but instead I want it to have and use the same IP address as the host machine.

For example, if the host's IP was 178.18.145.763 I would want the guest to use exactly the same IP, and for it to show up as being that IP instead of being assigned a new one dynamically.

The reason for this is because I am installing Plesk on the Windows guest and I want it to see what the real IP of the host OS is.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use same IP address. In that setup it is not possible to share same IP address *and* have working network.

Best way to fix it is to figure out how to specify IP address to Plesk manually. There is some articles in Parallels knowledge base, for example [this one](http://kb.parallels.com/1984).

Comment: Well, the host could be set up with NAT and port forwarding to the guest... which would give the illusion (from the outside) of the host and guest having the same IP address.

Comment: Well, if you read the original question, the point was to duplicate host setup exactly. Using NAT and internal IP address is problem with Plesk.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then that is **impossible**. You can configure the guest to be NAT'ed, so connections going out would get the IP of the guest, so other machines would see all connections comming from both guest and host with the same IP. But locally they *have* to have different IP's.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation .

Answer (score 0):

Could you use bridged mode and set a static IP Address, not the same as the host OS, but at least on the same subnet?

This is what I do for a Virtual Machine that must be on the same subnet as client devices (host OS is  Windows 7, guest OS is Windows Server 2008).